# C# with QuickGraph package from NuGet

Tags: c#, import, nuget, using, quickgraph

I have a **problem** while trying to use **AdjacencyGraph class of QuickGraph** package. Allow me to show my code as first and then describe the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using QuickGraph;

public class StrategicMap
{

    private IList<Fraction> fractions;
    private AdjacencyGraph<ProvinceOnMap, EdgeOnMap> provinces;

    public StrategicMap(IList<Fraction> fractions, AdjacencyGraph<ProvinceOnMap, EdgeOnMap> provinces)
    {
        this.fractions = fractions;
        this.provinces = provinces;
    }
```

[image]

I'm using a proper(?) import, well, "using". However, the compiler still doesn't know which class I refer to. From `QuickGraph.Contracts` or from `QuickGraph`.

Here is the last screenshot, which is telling more about the prob:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quite late with the answer, but perhaps it'll help you, or somebody else.
There are a few QuickGraph packages on NuGet.
I'm using this one
https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickGraphPCL/
and this seems to work fine.